# Need to delete CString after use to free memory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cstring

If I am using a CString like this:

```
void myFunc(char *str)
{
  CString s(str);
  // Manipulate other data with CString
  // ...
  // Finished

  // Should I somehow delete 's' here to avoid a memory leak?
}
```

Is the string erased once the function goes out of scope?

Also, I know that the `new` keyword allocates memory, if I construct an object without the `new` keyword, is memory still allocated? My intuition tells me yes, but I would like to verify.

e.g.

```
CString *asdf = new CString("ASDF");
// same as?
CString asdf("ASDF");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`new` allocates memory on the **heap**, so

```
CString *asdf = new CString("ASDF");
```

Allocates a `CString` on the heap and assigns a pointer to it to `asdf`. That memory will not be freed, nor will the destructor of `asdf` be called until you call `delete asdf`.

Without `new`, you are allocating on the **stack**, so

```
CString asdf("ASDF");
```

allocates stack memory, which `asdf` represents. This memory is automatically reclaimed when the stack is unwound (as in when you return from a function) and the destructor of `asdf` is automatically called when it goes out of scope.

Also, `CString` cleans up its own resources, so if the `CString` object is cleaned up (goes out of scope if it's on the stack or is deleted if it's on the heap), the resources it uses will also be cleaned up.

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense. Thanks for the clarification. This was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`CString` manages the memory for the string characters itself, so it will take care of freeing such memory at its destructor *(its a bit smarter, but think of it that way)*.

If you allocate a `CString` with `new` and never call `delete` on it not only are you leaking the memory for the `CString` object, but also its destructor is never called so you leak the memory for the string characters as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a CString object in most cases you'll end up with two allocations, one for the object itself and one for the characters of the string. The character allocation is hidden within the object and you don't have to worry about it. If you declare the object as an automatic variable as in your first example, the object will be deallocated at the end of the block i.e. the closing brace. If you allocate it with `new` you must later `delete` it or there will be a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate an object on the stack (ie if you don't use new) then it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope at the end of the function.