# Does JNA free memory of Go CString return value

Tags: java, jna, cgo

I have a JNA interface like this:

```java
interface JJ {
    String Hello(GoString.ByValue sql);
}
```

Corresponding native code in Go:

```golang
//export Hello
func Hello(ss string) *C.char {

    s := ss + " world"
    return C.CString(s)
}
```

The native code returns a pointer to a string.

Does JNA code free the pointer of the string allocated by the native code?
If not, how to free it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer both the generic question and the specific example.

JNA doesn't maintain any references to the native memory unless you allocate it yourself in JNA (e.g., define a `byte[]` array or `Memory` buffer that you pass to a function).  In these cases, the native memory is freed when the Java object is garbage collected.

If you're not passing any memory to C to fill, JNA isn't going to do anything with the native memory, and you'd have to read the API documentation to see what your responsibility is for freeing the native string.

The C++ CString type isn't necessarily required to be freed [unless it is stored in a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937561/1161484).  However, Go does implement the `CString` as an object, and documents these requirements.  For your particular example, [the docs](https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo) say:

> Memory allocations made by C code are not known to Go's memory
>   manager. When you create a C string with C.CString (or any C memory
>   allocation) you must remember to free the memory when you're done with
>   it by calling C.free.

and from the [cgo wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo):

> One important thing to remember is that C.CString() will allocate a
>   new string of the appropriate length, and return it. That means the C
>   string is not going to be garbage collected and it is up to you to
>   free it. A standard way to do this follows.

```
// #include <stdlib.h>

import "C"
import "unsafe"
...
    var cmsg *C.char = C.CString("hi")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cmsg))
    // do something with the C string
```

> Of course, you aren't required to use defer to call C.free(). You can
>   free the C string whenever you like, but it is your responsibility to
>   make sure it happens.

Comment: as [docs](https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo) say CString copies and allocates a new string which needs to be freed explicitly, so its not allocated on stack infact

Comment: @pdeva thanks, I've updated my answer. I don't know if that's a peculiarity with Go. I based my answer on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937561/1161484).  It may be that Go internally calls the `new` variant.

Answer (score 1):

Get Java to allocate the buffer so it will free it for you instead.. otherwise you MUST free it yourself and export deallocate functions..

```
public interface JJ {
    JJ lib = (JJ)Native.loadLibrary("jj.so", JJ.class);

    void Hello(byte[] sql);
}

func Hello(ss []byte) {
    copy(ss[:], string(ss) + " world")
}
```

Usage:

```
void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] text = new byte[256];

    JJ.lib.Hello(text);

    System.out.println(Native.toString(text));
}
```

You can wrap the entire thing into a generic function that will create a string for you for any given native function.. but you get the idea.

1. Java allocates buffer, Go-Lang fills it, Java deallocates it automatically.
2. Go-Lang allocates buffer, Java uses it, Go-Lang frees it.

In both cases, whoever allocates the buffer must free it.